# ReportBuilder 15.0. Convert and concatenate all checkbox values selected

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

Receiving True / False values from check boxes, converting to drug class 'Name", then required to concatenate field to report all values selected in DB.

Variable will compile and reports no errors however I am currently receiving only "Opiates" if selected otherwise receiving "Amphetamines" if selected or ", Amphetamines" irrespective of any other values selected.

No access to DB structure.

```
   Value := '';

        if People['Test Result 1'] = 'T' then 
        begin
        Value := 'Opiates';
         end;

        if People['Test Result 2'] = 'T'  then

          if  Value = '' then 
            Value := 'Amphetamine';
         end;
         else
                Value := Value + ', Amphetamine';
          end;

        if People['Test Result 3'] = 'T' then
         begin
          if  Value = '' then 
            Value := 'Benzodiazepines';
         end;
         else
                Value := Value + ', Benzodiazepines';
         end; 

         if People['Test Result 4'] = 'T'  then
         begin
           if  Value := '' then 
              Value := 'Cannabis';
        end;
        else
                Value := Value + ', Cannabis';

         end;          
         if People['Test Result 5'] = 'T'  then
          begin
          if  Value := '' then 
            Value := 'Methamphetamines';
          end;
          else
                Value := Value + ', Methamphetamines';
          end; 

         if People['Test Result 6'] = 'T' then

          if   Value := '' then 
            Value := 'Cocaine';
          end;
          else
                Value := Value + ', Cocaine';            
          end;
```

Now working

```
 Value := '';

  if People['Test Result 1'] = 'T' then 
   Value := 'Opiates';

   if People['Test Result 2'] = 'T'  then
   if value <> '' then
   Value := Value + ', Amphetamine'
    else
     Value := 'Amphetamine';

 if People['Test Result 3'] = 'T' then
  if value <> '' then
  Value := Value + ', Benzodiazepines'
   else
  Value := 'Benzodiazepines';

  if People['Test Result 4'] = 'T'  then
   if value <> '' then
   Value := Value + ', Cannabis'
   else
    Value := 'Cannabis';

   if People['Test Result 5'] = 'T'  then
  if value <> '' then
   Value := Value + ', Methamphetamines'
 else
   Value := 'Methamphetamines';

if People['Test Result 6'] = 'T' then
 if value <> '' then
 Value := Value + ', Cocaine' 
 else
  Value := 'Cocaine';
```

Comment: It should not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Far too much code, with some major errors.

Something like this should work:

```
Value := '';

if People['Test Result 1'] = 'T' then 
  Value := 'Opiates, ';

if People['Test Result 2'] = 'T'  then
  Value := Value + 'Amphetamine, ';

if People['Test Result 3'] = 'T' then
  Value := Value + 'Benzodiazepines, ';

if People['Test Result 4'] = 'T'  the
  Value := Value + 'Cannabis, ';

if People['Test Result 5'] = 'T'  then
  Value := Value + 'Methamphetamines, ';

if People['Test Result 6'] = 'T' then
  Value := Value + 'Cocaine, ';            

// Remove the extra trailing ', '
if Value <> '' then
  SetLength(Value, Length(Value) - 2);
```

If it were me, I'd probably configure this to use an array of results and a loop to go through the possibilities, but I don't know enough about what you're doing to code it. Here's some pseudocode that might give you an idea (untested, and made no effort to compile it; just a conceptual idea to perhaps help):

```
// Possible test results. Showing 3 for simplicity
const
  aResults: array[1..3] of string = ('Opiates', 'Amphetamines', 'Cannabis');
  sFmt := 'Test Result %d';
var
  i: Integer;
  Fld: string;
begin
  // Value defined wherever your previous one was
  Value := '';
  for i := Low(aResults) to High(aResults) do
  begin
    // Loop through fields (Test Result 1, Test Result 2, etc.)
    Fld := Format(sFmt, [i]);  
    if People[Fld] = 'T' then
      Value := Value + aResults[i] + ', ';
  end;
  // Remove extra ', '
  if Value <> '' then
    SetLength(Value, Length(Value) - 2);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. had issue with SetLength- "Undeclared identifier" ?? however the below is now geeting the required results. Fairly new at this but will take a look at the more elegant solution you have put forward as well, Thank you again.